# / AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a problem with splitting strings that are inside of my list. The code is supposed to split the strings in the list and than input them into a message to send in an email.

```
def report(db_connection, hours_back):
    #create a string out of all the measurements
    time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_before = time_now - datetime.timedelta(hours=hours_back)
    measurements = select_measurements_for_report(db_connection, hours_back)

    split = measurements.split(',')
    new_measurements = [split.split() for i in sents if i]

    message = """\
    Report data from {0} to {1}

    {2}

    """.format(time_before, time_now, new_measurements)

    send_mail(message)
```

This is the example measurements being inputted into measurements

```
[Measurement(measurementID=1, startTime=1555960632.4752572, endTime=1555960832.4752572, duration=100.0, channel=1, dataCounters=None), Measurement(measurementID=2, startTime=1555960532.4752572, endTime=1555960732.4752572, duration=100.0, channel=1, dataCounters=None), Measurement(measurementID=3, startTime=1555960432.4752572, endTime=1555960632.4752572, duration=100.0, channel=1, dataCounters=None), Measurement(measurementID=4, startTime=1555960332.4752572, endTime=1555960532.4752572, duration=100.0, channel=1, dataCounters=None)]
```

I'm expecting an output such as:

```
[measurementID=1, startTime=1555960632.4752572, endTime=1555960832.4752572, duration=100.0, channel=1, dataCounters=None), measurementID=2, startTime=1555960532.4752572, endTime=1555960732.4752572, duration=100.0, channel=1, dataCounters=None), measurementID=3, startTime=1555960432.4752572, endTime=1555960632.4752572, duration=100.0, channel=1, dataCounters=None), measurementID=4, startTime=1555960332.4752572, endTime=1555960532.4752572, duration=100.0, channel=1, dataCounters=None)]
```

Comment: Is `measurements` a `str` or a `list`?  You can only use `split` from an object of type `str`.

Comment: Just a comment: I would avoid overriding builtin functions like split. And split only works on strings anyways.

Comment: `[split.split() for i in sents if i]` can't work, `split` is a list

Comment: Then how do I go upon splitting up the list's objects?

Comment: add an example of `measurements` and `new_measurements`. Too few infos to answer.

Comment: I put in an example of measurements above in the original post. New measurements is the split up measurements, I outline how I want it to look.

Comment: is `measurements` a list or a string? what you have posted looks to me a list of `Measurement` objects. and what is `sents`?